# Add websites that should allow cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I'm trying to add a trusted website for cookies to **Google Chrome** using Javascript.
[image: Cookie section]

I can't use cookies normally cause they are disabled.
Cause of that I'm trying to add a website to the list of "trusted" websites for cookies so that I will be able to use them.
[image: Where I have to add the website]

Is there any way to add a trusted website for cookies with JavaScript?
Or is there any way to do that via code?

(I can't enable cookies so the only way to do that is adding a trusted website)

Comment: Could you please translate the text in images because I don't understand your language?

Comment: First picture: Cookies and other datas from website (you find em in google settings). Click on it

Second picture: Go to the bottom of cookies page and you should see "Website that can always use cookies"

I need to add a website to that list with javascript or via code if there is a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically it's not possible to add cookies with js if the "don't allow cookies" options is ticked. That's because of security issues.